# Error in displaying different files on my Android App

Tags: android, android-file

I'm trying to display different types of files on my android app, but it worked only with PDF files and when I try to display any other type of files. I get an error saying:

> Can't display pdf, invalid file format

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
  else if (currentFile.toString().contains(".pdf")) {

  String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(".PDF");
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(currentFile), mime);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 10);

} else if (currentFile.toString().contains(".doc")||currentFile.toString().contains(".docx")) {

  String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(".doc");

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(currentFile), mime);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 10);

} else if (currentFile.toString().contains(".jpg") || currentFile.toString().contains(".jpeg") || currentFile.toString().contains(".png")){
   String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(".jpg");

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(currentFile), mime);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the solution myself and here is the snippet of the code I've used

```
private void openFile(File currentFile, String fileFormat) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(currentFile),fileFormat);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and I called this method as following:

```
...........

                } else if (currentFile.toString().contains(".pdf"))
                openFile(currentFile,"application/pdf");

             else if (currentFile.toString().contains(".doc") || currentFile.toString().contains(".docx"))
                openFile(currentFile,"application/msword");

             else if (currentFile.toString().contains(".jpg") ||
                    currentFile.toString().contains(".jpeg") || currentFile.toString().contains(".png"))
                openFile(currentFile,"image/jpeg");
             else if(currentFile.toString().contains(".ppt") || currentFile.toString().contains(".pptx"))
                 // Powerpoint file
                openFile(currentFile,"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
             else if(currentFile.toString().contains(".xls") || currentFile.toString().contains(".xlsx"))
                // Excel file
                openFile(currentFile, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
              else if(currentFile.toString().contains(".zip") || currentFile.toString().contains(".rar"))
                // WAV audio file
                openFile(currentFile,"application/x-wav");

             else if(currentFile.toString().contains(".rtf"))
                // RTF file
                openFile(currentFile,"application/rtf");

             else if(currentFile.toString().contains(".wav") || currentFile.toString().contains(".mp3"))
                // WAV audio file
                openFile(currentFile,"audio/x-wav");

             else if(currentFile.toString().contains(".gif"))
                // GIF file
                openFile(currentFile,"image/gif");
             else if(currentFile.toString().contains(".txt"))
                // Text file
                openFile(currentFile,"text/plain");
```